# SQL Join With Counter

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL join function ready to implement however, if I run the snippet below only rows from wp_tours_tours are returned which also have rows in wp_tours_tours_bookings.

```
SELECT
wp_tours_tours.*, 
SUM(wp_tours_tours_bookings.qty) AS "TotalBookings"

FROM wp_tours_tours
left join wp_tours_tours_bookings ON wp_tours_tours.tour_id=wp_tours_tours_bookings.tour_id 
WHERE wp_tours_tours.post_id=12
```

If I use the below script without the SUM() function in the select statement it returns multiple rows (even those without any rows in wp_tours_tours_bookings)

```
SELECT
wp_tours_tours.*

FROM wp_tours_tours
left join wp_tours_tours_bookings ON wp_tours_tours.tour_id=wp_tours_tours_bookings.tour_id 
WHERE wp_tours_tours.post_id=12
```

I need to get the first snippet working so that it just returns 0 for "TotalBookings" if it has no rows and to pull through all data from tours_tours even if tours_tours_bookings has no rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a correlated subquery here:

```
select 
    t.*,
    (
        select coalesce(sum(tb.qty), 0) 
        from wp_tours_tours_bookings tb 
        where tb.tour_id = t.tour_id
    ) as totalbookings
from wp_tours_tours t
where t.post_id=12
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is malformed, because you have an aggregation function (`SUM()`) and columns that are not aggregated -- but no `GROUP BY`.

You need a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT tt.*, COALESCE(SUM(ttb.qty), 0) AS TotalBookings
FROM wp_tours_tours tt LEFT JOIN
     wp_tours_tours_bookings ttb
     ON tt.tour_id = ttb.tour_id 
WHERE tt.post_id = 12
GROUP BY tt.tour_id;  -- or whatever the primary key is
```

You can also use a correlated subquery (which probably has better performance):

```
SELECT tt.*,
       (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(ttb.qty), 0)
        FROM wp_tours_tours_bookings ttb
        WHERE tt.tour_id = ttb.tour_id 
       ) AS TotalBookings
FROM wp_tours_tours tt
WHERE tt.post_id = 12
```